# JSF 2.0: Action doesn't work

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I set up a JSF2.0 project with maven. Everything works fine exept action handling :-(

Here is my .xhtml page:

```
<h:form>
   <h:commandButton
        id="submit"
        value="Absenden"
        action="#(projectController.saveProject)">
   </h:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

and here my managed bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class ProjectController {

 public String saveProject(){
  System.out.println("test");
  return("/newProject.xhtml");
 }
...
```

When I try pushing the button nothing happens. No error-message...nothing. But data-binding works! Only actions/actionlisteners don't work

Maybe somebody has an answer for me :-)
Cheers

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your action is misspelled. Use curly brackets, then it should work:

```
action="#{projectController.saveProject}">
```